# CVCalendar iOS disabling dates not working when changing months

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, nscalendar

I am using [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) in an iPhone app and want to disable dates that are outside of a range. The dates on the calendar should only be enabled if they are between 4 and 14 days in the future. I have a function called `disableOutsideDays()` with attempts to accomplish this but it only works sporadically, like when the calendar view first appears, but not when the user scrolls to the next or previous months.

```
func disableOutsideDays() {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    for weekV in calendarView.contentController.presentedMonthView.weekViews {
        for dayView in weekV.dayViews {


            if calendar.compareDate(dayView.date.convertedDate()!, toDate: NSDate(), toUnitGranularity: .Day) == .OrderedAscending || calendar.compareDate(dayView.date.convertedDate()!, toDate: calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 14, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!, toUnitGranularity: .Day) == .OrderedDescending {
                dayView.userInteractionEnabled = false
                dayView.dayLabel.textColor = calendarView.appearance.dayLabelWeekdayOutTextColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call that inside `viewDidLoad` as well as `didShowNextMonthView` and `didShowPreviousMonthView`. The strange part is that scrolling to the next month could show all the days as enabled (opposite of what I want), but then scrolling back to the current month and back to the next one again shows them as disabled.

Comment: have you tried asking the question on github?

Answer (score 0):

For CVCalendar use this code to disable the dates outside of particular range.

**For Example:**
If you want user to access all dates between **2017-08-22** to **2017-09-22** , use below two functions directly inside your viewcontroller class with start and end date.

```
func earliestSelectableDate() -> Date {

        let dateStr = "2017-08-22 12:25:21 +0000" // Date after which all dates will get disabled

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateStr)!
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date)
        let startDate = calendar.date(from:components)

        return startDate!
    }


func latestSelectableDate() -> Date {

        let dateStr = "2017-09-22 12:25:21 +0000"

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateStr)!
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date)
        let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)

        return finalDate!
    }
```

**Note:-** This won't work in week view mode